# Matching based on whether year is included (at all) in date range

Tags: sql, oracle, date, between

I am attempting to join two tables based on date ranges.

Table A format is:

```
ID   CAT    DATE_START    DATE_END
1    10     2018-01-01    2020-12-31
2    15     2018-06-01    2018-07-01
```

Table B format is:

```
ID    YEAR       VALUE
1     2017       100
1     2018       110
1     2019       90
1     2020       30
2     2018       200
```

The resulting table should be merged if for a given ID, any of the days in B.YEAR are included in the date range from A.DATE_START to A.DATE_END, and should look like this:

```
ID    YEAR    CAT    VALUE
1     2018    10     110
1     2019    10     90
1     2020    10     30
2     2018    15     200
```

I tried merging using `extract(year from DATE_START)`  and `extract(year from DATE_START)`, but I cannot manage to include the middle year 2019 in the interval, which means ID = 1 is missing its 2019 value.

I also tried merging using `to_date(YEAR), 'YYYY')`, but the generated date for YEAR = '2018' is '1.9.2018', which does not fall in the interval for ID = 2. Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join the tables like this:

```
select a.ID, b.YEAR, a.CAT, b.VALUE 
from TableA a inner join TableB b
on b.ID = a.ID 
and b.year between extract(year from a.DATE_START) and extract(year from a.DATE_END)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=748c4d1b42fd0e0858bfd006e126dd85).
Results:

```
> ID | YEAR | CAT | VALUE
> -: | ---: | --: | ----:
>  1 | 2018 |  10 |   110
>  1 | 2019 |  10 |    90
>  1 | 2020 |  10 |    30
>  2 | 2018 |  15 |   200
```

Comment: Why are you joining on ID? I believe that would give incorrect results.

Comment: It is not ambiguous if you check the expected results. The join must be based also on the ids.

Comment: After looking over his data, I agree with you. I based my initial assumption of not using the ID based on "The resulting table should be merged if any of the days in B.YEAR are included in the date range from A.DATE_START to A.DATE_END" which did not mention a requirement to join on ID.

Comment: Thank you and big plus for the demo!

Answer (score 2):

First: I use Microsoft SQL Server, so apologies if this doesn't work in Oracle.

```
SELECT * FROM TableA 
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.Id = TableB.Id AND TableB.Year BETWEEN YEAR(TableA.Date_Start) AND YEAR(TableA.Date_End)
```

Comment: This method should work, but you will need to adapt YEAR to use Extract since YEAR is strictly a Microsoft function.

Comment: @AbrahamLincoln . . . `YEAR()` is supported in most databases, Oracle being an exception.  That said, `EXTRACT()` is the standard.

Comment: I modified my solution to include the ID. Although the author didn't state he was joining on ID as well, the expected result indicates he has this expectation.

I would accept forpas' solution as the accepted answer since it uses Oracle SQL syntax rather than the Microsoft syntax I used.

Comment: My apologies for being unclear, the join should also include the ID's, I will edit. Thanks for your quick answer!